# Why is the matrix element in the integral for cross section?

Tags: particle-physics, scattering-cross-section

The cross section $\sigma$ for a 2 particle reaction is:
$$\sigma=\frac{1}{2c}\frac{1}{h^4}\frac{p}{c^2}\frac{E_1E_2}{E_1+E_2}\int|\mathcal{A}_{fi}|^2\mathrm{d}\Omega_1$$
My question is now why the matrix element $\mathcal{A}_{fi} $ is in the integral. It would make no sense for me if the the matrix element is dependent of the solid angle and it would be also a contradiction to Fermis golden rule. So is the matrix element only in the integral for convention and to be clearer that the differential cross section is proportional to the matrix element?

Comment: This is an expression for the *total* cross section, not for the *differential* cross section.

Comment: @mikestone yes thats clear but I assumed with $\sigma\propto\int|\mathcal{A}_{fi}|^2\mathrm{d}\Omega$ it‘s better to see that for the differential cross section the “Integral cancels out when we differentiate”.

Comment: The matrix element is not, in general, a constant. It depends on the angle between the incoming and outoing momenta.

Comment: @mikestone thanks but is the cross section not proportional to the matrix element squared according to Fermis golden rule?

Comment: Im not sure what you are getting at. There is no single "matrix element". If the incoming momentum is   ${\bf p}$ and outgoing momentum is ${\bf p}'$. then  $A_{fi}=A_{{\bf p}{\bf p}'}$ depends on the angle between ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf p}'$.  Thus  $|A_{{\bf p}{\bf p}'}|^2$ gives the differential cross section, but you have to integrate over the solid angle to get the total cross section.

Comment: @mikestone is the following equation not true for a scattering process? $\sigma=\frac{V}{v}\cdot\omega_{fi}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\mathcal{A}_{fi}|^2\rho(E_f)$. Where $v$ is the relative velocity, $V$ is the interaction volume, $\omega_{fi}$ is the transition rate and $\rho(E_f)$ is the density of states of the final state. Because then the matrix element is independent of the solid angle according to the equation.

Comment: No it not true. That is the formula for $d\sigma/d\Omega$

Comment: @mikestone but for 2 colliding particle beams $a$ and $b$ with the density $n$ we get: $\omega_{fi}=\frac{\dot{N}_S}{N_aN_b}=\frac{(v_a+v_b)n_an_bV\sigma}{n_an_bV^2}=\frac{v}{V}\sigma$.

Comment: Where do you get these formulae from?

Comment: @mikestone it‘s from my lecture but I didn’t found the source. However for me they make intuitive sense and I don‘t see any mistakes..